# Unable to execute command: killed 9 in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, clang

I have a unity project that i'm building for iOS. I've included EasyAR, OneSignal, Firebase Analytics in the project.

It is working fine on Android without ant hiccups.

But on iOS I get this error in Xcode:

> clang: error: unable to execute command: Killed: 9
>   clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
>   Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)
>   Target: aarch64-apple-darwin17.5.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
>   PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
>   Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/fq/1sb3yqqx5s75s2h8m5z56fwm0000gn/T/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7-05e3fe.cpp
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/fq/1sb3yqqx5s75s2h8m5z56fwm0000gn/T/Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_7-05e3fe.sh
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/amit/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang__.crash
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:

---

Unity version: 2017.3
Xcode: 9.3

Comment: You need to provide some code files and a more indepth explanation about what is generating this error

Comment: Are you using visual machine?

Comment: I'm not sure what is generating that error, i have very little experience with Xcode.

Comment: no i:m not using a virtual machine, I;m using the Macbook Air

Comment: Can you re-run the program with `-v` and post the full error?

Answer (score -1):

i met the some problem and solve it

with c# code

```
public class SomeWord
{
    public static List<string> Words = new List<string>(new string[]
    {
        "aaa"
        , "bbb"
        , "ccc"
        , "ddd"
        , "eee"
        , "fff"
        , "ggg"
        // the list has 3w ele
```

il2cpp convert this to

```
extern "C"  void SomeWord__cctor_m3830774958 (Il2CppObject * __this /* static, unused */, const MethodInfo* method)
{
    static bool s_Il2CppMethodInitialized;
    if (!s_Il2CppMethodInitialized)
    {
        il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (SomeWord__cctor_m3830774958_MetadataUsageId);
        s_Il2CppMethodInitialized = true;
    }
    {
        StringU5BU5D_t1642385972* L_0 = ((StringU5BU5D_t1642385972*)SZArrayNew(StringU5BU5D_t1642385972_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var, (uint32_t)((int32_t)26109)));
        NullCheck(L_0);
        ArrayElementTypeCheck (L_0, _stringLiteral1002530778);
        (L_0)->SetAt(static_cast<il2cpp_array_size_t>(0), (String_t*)_stringLiteral1002530778);
        StringU5BU5D_t1642385972* L_1 = L_0;
        NullCheck(L_1);
        ArrayElementTypeCheck (L_1, _stringLiteral632527236);
        (L_1)->SetAt(static_cast<il2cpp_array_size_t>(1), (String_t*)_stringLiteral632527236);
        StringU5BU5D_t1642385972* L_2 = L_1;
        NullCheck(L_2);
        // this style of code repeat nearly 3w times
```

just pick out the string in list and put it in a file, then read in from file solve the problem. the c# code is auto generate with some reason maybe i don't know why. next time if someone meet the same problem, do with this step:

1) check out the xcode compile step and find out which file cost a lot of time

2) open the file and find if there is some weird function with a lot of statement in

3) find out which c# file convert to those code and change it

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use this. Could you please explain this in some detail.